# python lambda if/else condition failed : 'int' and 'function' conflicts

Tags: python

I'm trying to use in-line, lambda function to perform some if/else conditions, where I'm getting `"unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'"` error. Here I'm trying to set set_duration to 1.5 unless its first and last array iterations. Can you please take a look and offer any hints. Looking forward.

```
for idx, string in enumerate(lines):


    duration = 10
    clips = []

    clips.append(ImageClip(os.path.join(folder,"gradient.png"))
                 .set_duration(lambda idx: 3 if (idx == 0 and lines[len(lines) - 1]) else 1.5)
                 )

    clips.append(ImageClip(os.path.join(folder,"image-{0}.png"))
                 .resize(width=800)
                 .set_duration(lambda idx: 3 if (idx == 0 and lines[len(lines) - 1]) else 1.5)
                 .margin(right=60, opacity=0)
                 .set_pos(("right","center"))
                 )

    clips.append(ImageClip(os.path.join(folder, "big-append.png"))
                 .resize(width=900)
                 .margin(left=60,opacity=0)
                 .set_duration(lambda idx: 3 if (idx == 0 and lines[len(lines) - 1]) else 1.5)
                 .set_pos(("left", "center"))
                 )



// rest of the code...
```

FullTraceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\vhosts\phpsols\pymovie\FORMAT-4\three.py", line 90, in <module>
    .set_duration(lambda idx: 3 if (idx == 0 and lines[len(lines) - 1]) else 1.5)
  File "<decorator-gen-29>", line 2, in set_duration
  File "C:\anaconda32\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.2.11-py2.7.egg\moviepy\decorators.py", line 29, in apply_to_mask
    newclip = f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "<decorator-gen-28>", line 2, in set_duration
  File "C:\anaconda32\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.2.11-py2.7.egg\moviepy\decorators.py", line 41, in apply_to_audio
    newclip = f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "<decorator-gen-27>", line 2, in set_duration
  File "C:\anaconda32\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.2.11-py2.7.egg\moviepy\decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
  File "<decorator-gen-26>", line 2, in set_duration
  File "C:\anaconda32\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.2.11-py2.7.egg\moviepy\decorators.py", line 14, in outplace
    f(newclip, *a, **k)
  File "C:\anaconda32\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.2.11-py2.7.egg\moviepy\Clip.py", line 288, in set_duration
    self.end = None if (t is None) else (self.start + t)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'
Process terminated with an exit code of 1
```

Comment: EDIT: sorry, just a blind guess. Trying it out it works for me... are you sure that the error is pointing to this part of the code? You have no "+" here... the error basically says that you are trying to add INT and FUNCTION together :) As "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'" doesn't refer to "and" inside your lambda.

Comment: @PeterMajko, hi not so far

Comment: @PeterMajko, its moviepy module, so ImageClip is there standard class

Comment: @PeterMajko, full traceback added...

Comment: What is the value of "lines[len(lines) - 1]" when it throws the error?

Comment: If there is a function inside, perhaps you need: lines[len(lines) - 1]()

Comment: Here: `self.start + t` you are adding a function and an int, hence your traceback. Did you mean `self.start() + t` instead? (add `t` to the returned value from `self.start()`

Comment: Probably `t` here:  `self.end = None if (t is None) else (self.start + t)` is the function you passed to `set_duration`.

Comment: @SiHa That's the source code of MoviePy, the user is not going to change that.

Comment: The issue is in the lambda itself. With lambda you are creating FUNCTION object, not the result of running the function. `x = lambda idx: 3 if (idx == 0 and lines[len(lines) - 1]) else 1.5 type(x)` is function. As in the answer from kennytm, you don't need lambda here.

Comment: @PeterMajko, its works when I do use the lambda as suggested by some.

Comment: First understand the lambda. The lambda creates the function. Useful with another functions which based on some function do something :) like map or filter. Here it is not useful, as you want the result from the function right away as the input for your .set_duration()

Comment: @PeterMajko, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a lambda. Just set the duration directly. The value is already recalculated every loop iteration.

```
             .set_duration(3.0 if idx == 0 and lines[-1] else 1.5)
```

Comment: I still would like to see the reason behind the error though, even if such thing fixes the issue for the user :)

Comment: The edited question (with traceback) now shows that the problem is not here at all...

Comment: @PeterMajko: `.set_duration()` tries to compute `self.start + t` (see the stack trace), where `t` is the user's input, which is wrongly a lambda (function), and `self.start` is an integer. Thus the `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'` error.

Comment: Yes, I see now. Using lambda it would be: `.set_duration((lambda x: 3 if (x == 0 and lines[len(lines) - 1]) else 1.5)(idx))` quite overkill :D

Comment: @PeterMajko, yaap, but learning how use a lambda here is great :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a lambda at all in this case.  Just put the "3 if (idx ..." expression in the set_duration() calls.